# Jquery: tabbed menu navigation, activation and deactivation based on the menu selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four menu at the top such as `Home, Projects, About Us and Contact Us`, if i select any of the menu, then, the rest of the menus need to be hidden. For this case, I have managed with colors. when the menu activate, then, it should be in black, rest of them in white by updating css. It(this below code) works fine. But, i want to simplify this code as i think this seems large amount of code for that operation. How I can simplify this code to perform the same? Any help?

```
$("li[name='AboutUs']").click(function(){
$(this).attr("class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Contact']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Projects']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Home']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
});
$("li[name='Projects']").click(function(){
$(this).attr("class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Contact']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='AboutUs']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Home']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
});
$("li[name='Home']").click(function(){
$(this).attr("class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Contact']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='AboutUs']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Projects']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
});
$("li[name='Contact']").click(function(){
$(this).attr("class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Home']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='AboutUs']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
$("li[name='Projects']").removeAttr( "class", "selectedtab");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:** Assign some `id` to your `header` to discriminate other `ul` if at all they are on the page

```
 $("#header li").click(function(){
         $(this).attr("class", "selectedtab");
         $("#header li").not(this).removeAttr("class");

         });
```

sample html:

```
<ul id="header">
<li name="Home">Home</li>
<li name="Contact">Contact</li>
<li name="AboutUs">AboutUs</li>
<li name="Projects">Projects</li>

</ul>

<ul>

<li class="new">hiiiii</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are over complicating your structure by using name attribute selectors. Just create Id for all of them and then use [jQuery siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">

    <li>About Us</li> 
    <li>Contact</li>   
    <li>Projects</li>   
    <li>Home</li>   

</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#menu li").click(function(){

    $(this).removeClass("hide").addClass("selectedtab");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selectedtab").addClass("hide")

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xw1hkLjm/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").find(".selectedtab").removeClass("selectedtab");
$(this).addClass("selectedtab");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selectedtab');
    $('li').not(this).removeClass('selectedtab');
});
```

Comment: This is problematic if there are other `li` elements on the page that you don't want to affect.

Comment: Then he could target the specific li by their parent class or id: $('ul.your-list > li')